# Angular firebase database snapshot and valuechanges

Tags: database, angular, firebase

got one function which one works with `this.ShowVisualContent()` :

```
  getUploads() {
    this.uploads = this.db.list(`profile/${this.auth.userId}/projects/`).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
      return actions.map((a) => {
        const data = a.payload.val();
        this.showVisualContent(data.url, data.name);
        const $key = a.payload.key;
        const $ref = a.payload.ref;
        return { $key, ...data, $ref };
      });
    });
    return this.uploads;
  }
```

And now I got another one where I want to make the same but with valueChanges :

```
  this.uploads = this.db.list(`profile/${this.auth.userId}/projects/${this.projectId}`).valueChanges();
```

How to make both do the same ?

Edit :

Try 1 :

```
 upload: Observable<Project[]>;
  this.upload = this.db.list(`profile/${this.auth.userId}/projects/${this.projectId}`).valueChanges().map(data => {
      this.navSrv.showVisualContent(data.url, data.name);
      return data;
    });
```

ERROR :

> Type 'Observable[]>' is not assignable
>   to type 'Observable'.   Type
>   'AngularFireAction[]' is not assignable to type
>   'Project[]'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
this.db.list(`profile/${this.auth.userId}/projects/${this.projectId}`).valueChanges().subscribe 
( res => console.log (res), 
error => console.log (error), 
() => console.log ("complete") );
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your code. What does it do? How does this answer the question?